# Python pandas perform same aggregation on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I know that in pandas, I can do something like this, where I apply multiple aggregations to the **same column**:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,2], 'x1':[0,1,0,1], 'x2':[1,0,1,0],'x3':[0,1,0,1], 'x4':[1,0,1,0]})
df.groupby('id').agg({'x1':['sum', 'max'], 'x2':['sum','max']})
```

Is there a syntax shortcut to do a similar thing, except this time apply the **same aggregation** to multiple columns? However, I am also looking to perform more than one type of aggregation.

**Valid Syntax Example**

```
df.groupby('id').agg({'x1':sum, 'x2':sum, 'x3':mean, 'x4':mean})
```

**Desired Outcome Example**

```
df.groupby('id').agg({['x1', 'x2']:sum, ['x3', 'x4']:mean})
```

I know this isn't a valid key-value pair, but hopefully illustrates what I'm aiming for. As to why I want to do this, my current aggregation statement is getting long and I am looking for ways to shorten it.

Answer (score 3):

If want use `list` in keys of dictionary it is not valid in python.

---

Close, what you need is specify columns after `groupby`, but it working only for one aggregate function:

```
df.groupby('id')['x1', 'x2'].sum()
```

Or:

```
df.groupby('id')['x1', 'x2'].agg('sum')
```

---

If want some more dynamic solution one is create dictionary of tuples and then flatten values, only is necessary all values unique in tuples, because dict by definition has unique keys:

```
d = {('x1', 'x2'):['sum','max'], ('x3', 'x4'):'mean'}
d1 = {x:v for k, v in d.items() for x in k}
print (d1)
{'x1': ['sum', 'max'], 'x2': ['sum', 'max'], 'x3': 'mean', 'x4': 'mean'}

print (df.groupby('id').agg(d1))
    x1      x2       x3   x4
   sum max sum max mean mean
id                          
1    1   1   1   1  0.5  0.5
2    1   1   1   1  0.5  0.5
```

Comment: This does work for a single aggregation, but I realize I need to update my question with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a dictionary comprehension using `zip` on equal length lists/tuples of multiple columns and aggregates. Then pass dictionary into `groupby().agg`:

```
cols = [['x1', 'x2'], ['x3', 'x4']]
aggs = ['sum', 'mean']

d = {c:a for col,a in zip(cols, aggs) for c in col}

df.groupby('id').agg(d) 
#     x1  x2   x3   x4
# id                  
# 1    1   1  0.5  0.5
# 2    1   1  0.5  0.5
```