# Python pandas perform same aggregation on all other columns, whithout naming columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregation

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59602364/python-pandas-perform-same-aggregation-on-multiple-columns), when you want to apply the same aggregation function to multiple columns, you have to name columns. now consider a situation which i have many columns (30 columns for example). is there any way to do aggregation without naming columns? i mean is there any thing like this?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(...)
df.groupby('id').agg(lambda: col -> [sum(col) if col != id]);
```

Comment: Just `df.groupby('id').sum()` ?

Comment: i want to group by year,month,day (3 columns) and aggregate all other columns (they are different economical indexes i.e. stock prices) @JonClements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you linked uses `df.groupby('id')['x1', 'x2'].agg('sum')`.

So, to use every one of many columns but except a few ones:

```
columns_to_exclude = ['year', 'month' ,'day']
columns_to_aggregate = [col for col in df.columns if col not in columns_to_exclude]
df.groupby('id')[columns_to_aggregate].agg('sum')
```